# Add a column to a PL SQL report that has default data in it

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to add a column to a PL SQL query but the syntax is different than SQL and I am not sure how to do it. In SQL I could use:

```
SELECT CustomerName,"Big" AS Round FROM Customers;
```

And using the now famous northwind database this would result:

```
CustomerName / Round

Alfred / Big
```

But if I use this same syntax in PL SQL it results in a

> "ORA-00904: "Big": invalid identifier" error.

How do I create this column and populate it with the data I require?

Comment: use single tic's not double. and caution on the name round if it's used in a view as it's a reserved word.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes  `'`  rather than double `"` and your query should work.

```
SELECT CustomerName, 'Big' AS Round FROM Customers;
```